# can mceps be used to classfication audio's kind?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, classification, librosa

recently, im using mceps features extracted from audio data, but i found when using it to conuct classfication, experiment's result is bad. Wanna know if mcep can be used for classfication.

Comment: What do you mean by mcep? Do you mean MFCC? Mel Frequency Cepstral Coefficients? How are you calculating these features?

Comment: How is the classification set up, what is the task, what performance do you get, and what performance do you expect?